# button IBAction not working on a subview

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to `Swift` and `IOS` programming. All I do is having a subview call yearSelectionVC in the ViewController SelectionViewVC.

All I do in the SelectionViewVC is using the UISegmentedControl to change the subview to different ViewController. However, I am trying to add some button on the subview by interface builder and using `IBAction` to trigger some code when the button pressed, is not working at all. I have checked all the button in the subview has linked to the same `IBAction` code, what can I do to make those button working? Thanks for helping!

Note: the subview are created in a XIB file

```
class SelectionViewVC: UIViewController {
    var requestd_date:Date = Date()
    @IBOutlet weak var requested_date_label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewContainer: UIView!
    var views:[UIView]!
    static var selected_year = 0
    static var selected_month = 0
    static var selected_day = 0
    static var selected_hour = 0
    static var selected_minute = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        updateCurrentDate()
        SelectionViewVC.selected_year = current_year
        SelectionViewVC.selected_month = current_month
        SelectionViewVC.selected_day = current_day
        SelectionViewVC.selected_hour = current_hour
        SelectionViewVC.selected_minute = current_minute
        views = [UIView]()
        views.append(yearSelectionVC().view)
        views.append(monthSelectionVC().view)
        views.append(dateSelectionVC().view)
        views.append(hourSelectionVC().view)
        views.append(minuteSelectionVC().view)
        for view in views {
            viewContainer.addSubview(view)
        }
        viewContainer.bringSubview(toFront: views[0])
        let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Submit", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(SelectionViewVC.submitButtonTapped(_:)))

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
        let request_date_string = dateFormatter.string(from: requestd_date)
        requested_date_label.text = "Date Requested to input: \(request_date_string)"
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @objc func submitButtonTapped(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem){
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    @IBAction func switchViewAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        self.viewContainer.bringSubview(toFront: views[sender.selectedSegmentIndex])
    }
}

class yearSelectionVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var selected_date_label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var year1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year5: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year6: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year7: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year8: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year9: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year10: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year11: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year12: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year13: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year14: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year15: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var year16: UIButton!
    var yearButtonList:[UIButton]!
    var current_temp_year = 0
    var originalButtonColor:UIColor!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        yearButtonList = [UIButton]()
        yearButtonList.append(year1)
        yearButtonList.append(year2)
        yearButtonList.append(year3)
        yearButtonList.append(year4)
        yearButtonList.append(year5)
        yearButtonList.append(year6)
        yearButtonList.append(year7)
        yearButtonList.append(year8)
        yearButtonList.append(year9)
        yearButtonList.append(year10)
        yearButtonList.append(year11)
        yearButtonList.append(year12)
        yearButtonList.append(year13)
        yearButtonList.append(year14)
        yearButtonList.append(year15)
        yearButtonList.append(year16)
        current_temp_year = SelectionViewVC.selected_year
        updateSelectedDateText()
        originalButtonColor = yearButtonList[15].titleLabel?.textColor
        yearButtonList[0].setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        for year in current_temp_year...current_temp_year+15 {
            yearButtonList[year-current_temp_year].setTitle(String(describing:year), for: .normal)
            yearButtonList[year-current_temp_year].tag = year-current_temp_year
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func updateSelectedDateText() {
        selected_date_label.text = "Selected Date: \(SelectionViewVC.selected_year)/\(month_degit_list[SelectionViewVC.selected_month-1])/\(day_list[SelectionViewVC.selected_day-1]) \(hour_list[SelectionViewVC.selected_hour]):\(minute_list[SelectionViewVC.selected_minute])"
    }
    @IBAction func yearButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle("done", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the function is not being called using a breakpoint or a simple print statement in the action?

Comment: 2 things regarding possible improvements to your code: 1) it is considered standard in Swift to have class names be uppercased (`yearSelectionVC` –> `YearSelectionVC`). 2) Check out outlet collections to which you can connect all your buttons so you don't have to write `yearButtonList.append(...) ` for like 1000 times ;)

Comment: You have an IBAction, but what action is it tracking? You're likely tracking something that's not a touch, like `valueChanged`.

Comment: @BrunoRocha am tracking the Touch up Inside Event

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Thank for the suggestion :D